# Bing maps binding trouble

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, observablecollection, bing-maps

Im having a real headache binding my items to pushpins on a silverlight bing map.

Ive spent all day trying to get my collection sorted and now just cant get the pushpins to show up.

The items appear to be there as when you do a breakpoint on the last line as per the image below, all 143 items are there in _PushPins:

[image]

Any help welcome. many thanks.

Here is the code:

```
 namespace observable_collection_test
{
public partial class Map : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    public Map()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GetItems();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<SItem2> pushPins; 
    public ObservableCollection<SItem2> PushPins 
    {   
        get  { return this.pushPins; }   
        set   
        {     
         this.pushPins = value;

        this.OnPropertyChanged("PushPins");   
         } 
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }


 public void GetItems()
    {

         var document = XDocument.Load("ListSmall.xml");

         if (document.Root == null)
            return;

          var xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.blah");

         var events = from ev in document.Descendants("item")
          select new
          {
           Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(ev.Element(xmlns + "Point").Element(xmlns + "lat").Value),
            Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(ev.Element(xmlns + "Point").Element(xmlns + "long").Value),

         };

         this.PushPins = new ObservableCollection<SItem2>();   
         foreach (var ev in events)   
          {     
         var pushPin = new SItem2(ev.Latitude, ev.Longitude);
         //Location = new GeoCoordinate(ev.Latitude, ev.Longitude )
         this.PushPins.Add(pushPin);   
         } 
}
```

Other class:

```
namespace observable_collection_test
{
 public class SItem2
{
           public double Latitude
    { get; set; }
    public double Longitude
    { get; set; }

    public SItem2(double Latitude, double Longitude)
    {
                    this.Latitude = Latitude;
        this.Longitude = Longitude;
              }

    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
}
```

XAML:

```
 <my:Map ZoomBarVisibility="Visible" ZoomLevel="10" CredentialsProvider="xxxxx"  Height="508" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,22,0,0" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" ScaleVisibility="Visible">
                  <my:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PushPins}" >
                <my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>        
             <my:Pushpin Background="Aqua" Location="{Binding Location}" ManipulationCompleted="pin_click">
                        </my:Pushpin></DataTemplate>
                </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </my:MapItemsControl>
 </my:Map>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to bind to a private field, _PushPins, instead of the public property PushPins. Also  don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged if you're changing the collection after binding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin. I have edited my code and image to what I thought may be the issue. Still no joy. Do I need some sort of get set accesor for the  public ObservableCollection<SItem2> PushPins ?

Comment: Yes, you can only bind to properties, not fields.  Also, your XAML is still referencing _PushPins.

Comment: Ahh that use XAML was an error from playing around. schoolboy error.
I am not entirely sure what im doing with the get/set accessor there, ive edited it, and of course still no joy :( Im sure its obvious to a expert whats wrong here :-)

Comment: Are you getting a runtime error?  In your PushPins getter, you're returning the property value itself, which would cause a StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 1):

I would do two things - firstly, implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and have your PushPins property use a private backing field.  In the getter, just return the field value, in the setter, update the field value and invoke the PropertyChanged event.

Then, in your loop, rather than the getItems method (I would use PascalCase for method names) creating a local ObservableCollection, instantiate the PushPins collection and populate it directly.

```
private ObservableCollectin<SItem2> pushPins;
public ObservableCollection<SItem2> PushPins
{
  get { return this.pushPins; }
  set
  {
    this.pushPins = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged("PushPins");
  }
}

public void GetItems()
{
  ...

  this.PushPins = new ObservableCollection<SItem2>();
  foreach (var ev in events)
  {
    var pushPin = new SItem2(ev.Latitude, ev.Longitude);
    this.PushPins.Add(pushPin);
  }
}
```

Populate the SItem2 Location property in the SItem2 constructor instead using the lat/long, and as Martin says, if you want the UI to update when you change the value of an SItem2 instance in the collection, then implement INotifyPropertyChanged on SItem2's properties also.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Ive updated the code to my current state of play. Im unsure what im doing with the "Location = new GeoCoordinate(ev.Latitude, ev.Longitude )" to build the location items? Im sure my lack of knowledge is showing up here..

Comment: You aren't setting the Location value anywhere, in your SItem2 constructor you can set this.Location = new Location(this.Latitude, this.Longitude);